# Is it possible to get exact date with hour when timezone will change time?

Tags: python, date, datetime, timezone

Let's say I have timezone `"Europe/Warsaw"`.

I know that in Poland (Warsaw) time changes on `03-26 02:00:00` each year - from `+ 01:00` to `+ 02:00`. (eg. `2017-03-26 00:00:00 + 01:00`, `2017-03-27 00:00:00 + 02:00`)

If I didn't know that exact time change date, is there any way to automatically find it by having `"Europe/Warsaw"` timezone information only?

Comment: So you want to know when daylight saving time starts and ends?

Comment: Exactly. I state timezone and I would like to get those dates for that timezone.